# What liquid would wick away heat most quickly?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

I've read and seen on various "life hack" websites that if you've forgotten to chill drinks, wrapping them in a wet paper towel and sticking them in the freezer for a few minutes rapidly cools them down. Having tried it myself and found it works very effectively (normally resulting in a pepsi slushie thanks to my sieve-like memory), and having read [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107904/does-wrapping-a-wet-paper-towel-around-a-glass-bottle-really-speed-up-the-coolin), I've been led to wonder about a few things:

Is water the best liquid for this?
What property of a liquid would make it good at this process? I would assume it would be a low evaporation temperature, given that I think it works in a similar manner to sweating. It's been a while since I did any physics of heat, but I feel specific heat capacity might have something to do with it.
Would it be possible to have a container holding the liquid, rather than something like a paper towel? Or does the liquid need to be on the surface of the can? If it needs to evaporate, one would assume that it doesn't need to be on the surface but does need to be in the open (ish) air.
Would water at 90 degrees or water at 1 degree be better at this, or would it make no difference?

Comment: This is by no means an answer but a guess. I think that I have read that the water is actually evaporating from the paper towel in the situation you described. The explanation I read said that the water was evaporating and thus leaving with much of the heat. So perhaps something with that evaporates more quickly like alcohol.

Comment: @Jake - evaporation most likely plays a part. Be careful about placing open flammable liquids (alcohol, acetone, ether) in a fridge. When the thermostat kicks in, there can be a spark and an explosion. Seriously - I saw a live demo of this as part of a safety briefing. Fridge flew 50 feet into the air. Don't do it. Have you tried doing the experiment where you have two identical bottles in the freezer - one wrapped, and one bare? Is the difference real or perceived?

Comment: Yea that's probably smart. This isn't helped by the fact that things that evaporate quickly tend to be highly flammable. Also alcohol doesn't quite have the heat capacity of water so it might not be as effective without larger volumes of the stuff.

Comment: @Floris a fairly rudimentry experiment was carried out by a commentator in the question I linked to in the description, which showed that yes a reasonably noticeable difference is seen. Jake, I think you're right about evaporation, that's why I mentioned sweating - same process. The air in the freezer is dry, so the water pulls energy from the coke to evaporate. But as you say, there must be some trade off with evaporation point and specific heat capacity.